# xdvipdfmx:fatal: Image inclusion failed for "Pictures/citime.eps"

Tags: xetex, texstudio

Today when I compile the latex file in texstudio `TeXstudio 4.1.2 (git 4.1.2)` using this command(M1 pro macbook):

```
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "dolphin-book-2020".tex
```

show error like this:

```
Process started: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "dolphin-book-2020".tex

xdvipdfmx:fatal: Image inclusion failed for "Pictures/citime.eps".
No output PDF file written.
Error: Command crashed: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "dolphin-book-2020".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

why did this happen? I am using this eps file like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{citime.eps}
    \caption{构建优化前后时间对比}
    \label{fig:citime}
\end{figure}
```

what should I do avoid this problem? I found all the eps file did not work. I have already install the ghostscript:

```
➜  ~ brew install ghostscript
Warning: ghostscript 9.55.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 9.55.0, run:
  brew reinstall ghostscript
```

I finally found it works in MacBook Pro 2019 but not worked with the M1 MacBook Pro 2021.

Comment: the first step is to provide us we the need data to test your issue. Without the image, the description where it is stored and a complete example that is not possible.

Comment: Guess your use of `\graphicspath` contains an extra `/`.

Comment: Please include a minimal compilable example ao we can test for ourselves. What TeX Distribution are you using? If it's TeX Live 2021  try using the command line `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E"  -synctex=1  -interaction=nonstopmode "dolphin-book-2020".tex`.